# Why does my next.js application crashes on some devices?

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps

I have an next.js application that crashes when used on some devices.
I have no idea what's going on and I tested in several browser with e2e, but the error persists:
[image]

I didn't try that much to spot the bug, because I don't know where to even start.